# How can I get the sum of array members?

Tags: php, foreach

This is an PHP array:

```
array
  'ItemId' => 
    array
      0 => string '32' (length=2)
      1 => string '33' (length=2)
      2 => string '35' (length=2)
  'ItemQty' => 
    array
      0 => string '2' (length=1)
      1 => string '1' (length=1)
      2 => string '1' (length=1)
```

What I like to achieve is to count the numbers in the strings in ItemQty

So here the outcome would be 4.

I tried to use a foreach loop but the outcome is always 3 not 4 (logical I think, but cant solve it)

The array above is a small version of a var_dump of POST values. Its for form validation.

```
$count_total = 0;

foreach ($jcart->get_contents() as $item) {     

            ++$count_total;

}
```

What is also seems to make complicated is that $jcart->get_contents() is not just an normal array. At least I don't now how to apply it to the solutions beneath.

var_dump($jcart); gives an object in which the total is already stored as well

private 'itemCount' => int 4

Comment: count the numbers? or sum them? - if it's the former then 3 is correct.

Comment: Are you wanting to add the values together? eg 2+1+1?

Comment: @Bankzilla yes I like to

Comment: Why are you values returning as strings and not integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php).

```
$sum = array_sum($arr['ItemQty']);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
echo array_sum(array_map('intval', $data['ItemQty']))
```

This will call `intval()` for each item in the `$data['ItemQty']` array and then call `array_sum` to give you the sum of the result.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($array['ItemQty'] as $val) {
  $sum += $val;
}
```

Comment: The `$count` var is a bit misleading, as this does not count the values, but rather sums it up.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to sum the numbers you can utilise `array_sum()`, if it's a single dimensional array. Or, alternatively, you can use a `foreach` loop and iterate through it whilst adding to a `sum` var, like so:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($item in $items) {
    $sum += $item;
}
```

Since your question can also mean *count* all values in an array. You can use PHP's `count()` function to count the total values in an array.